# Can't see any object in Solid mode, material mode except the selection silhouette but can see in render mode

Tags: materials, edit-mode, object-mode

As I open Blender I can't see the default cube or any object in solid mode and material mode in object view but can see in edit-view as in the image, I can only see the selection silhouette. I made sure I was not hiding any objects etc. I tried restarting blender 2.8 but it didn't work, I uninstalled and installed blender 2.82, and it has the same issue. I also had blender 3.2.1 already installed meanwhile, when opening this version everything works perfectly, but as I also want to use blender 2.82 because of an addon it isn't working as described.

[image: version][image: layout][image: collection view][image: edit-mode]

Answer (score 0):

In the *Viewport Shading* options, please make sure *X-Ray* isn't set to 0 (it should be 1 by default).

If that solve your problem, don't forget to save your startup file (*File/Defaults/Save Startup File*)